# Simple HTTP TCP implementation does not snap out of InputStream while loop of reading HTTP Request header

Tags: java

I wanted to write a simple HTTP server just for exercise, and I'm 20 lines in and already stuck.

```
package httpd;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Httpd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1500);
                Socket sock = server.accept();
                InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();) {

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(b);
            }

            System.out.println("Sending HTTP Response");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is all fine, the header gets written to the `out` stream in my console:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1500
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And thatls it. It's just sitting there afterwards. It never prints `Sending HTTP Response` and just sits there. Google Chrome is spinning the spinner backwards, awaiting a response. They both hang until i kill the page in Google Chrome, and then the server prints `Sending HTTP Response`

I can't respond unless the `while` loop is broken, and it won't break for some reason. Why?

EDIT:

```
package httpd;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Httpd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1500);
            Socket sock = server.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(b);
            }

            System.out.println("Sending HTTP Response");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This works. And I have no idea why. Could someone explain?

Comment: Will `try (` even compile?

Comment: Look up try-with-resources. Its the equivalent of calling .close() on all the resources inside the () brackets, in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the TCP connection is still open (since the client is waiting for a response), so the input stream isn't ended, so `read()` blocks instead of returning -1. I'm guessing the BufferedReader's logic is different for some reason.

Read this for how to detect the end of the request:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

If you're just handling GET, then you can just look for `\n\n`, but handling POST will require something more complicated.